# AKS traffic issues after Istio install

Tags: istio, azure-aks

Has anyone else been experiencing severe networking issues after installing Istio onto a cluster?  We are seeing helm deploys (of other services) hang and fail as well as the kube dashboard runs extremely slow.  Kubectl commands still are quick (sub 200ms via -v=6).

This is after a vanilla Istio 0.8 install onto a fresh AKS (w/ RBAC enabled), have attempted various regions (East/West/Central US) and they all exhibit the same issue.

It's currently unusable for us, but maybe I'm just missing something, I haven't found any tickets about the same issue?  I believe this began happening about a week ago (6/27) which is around the time Microsoft made some changes to their AKS clusters, but we started using RBAC at the same time so it could be any combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue with istio v1.0, I think it's because of the continuously crashing galley instance in v1.0, but I did not experience such slowness with istio v0.8. Did you come up with a solution? For me it started to slow down when I deployed all my the applications.

The galley issue in v1.0 is solved by the way, it will be merged into the 1.0 release hopefully very soon. (https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/7605)